# Can Twitter widget display a user timeline AND hashtag search?

Tags: twitter

I am using the widget creator through Twitter's settings to display a Twitter timeline on my brother's website. I see four options for displaying Twitter feeds through this widget creator. These include: A User Timeline which displays the timeline of a user, Favorites which displays the favorites of a user, List which displays a list of users, and Search which displays tweets to a specific hashtag.

My brother wants his website's timeline to tweets from his username AND any tweets to a specific hashtag. So pretty much a combination of the User Timeline option and the Search option. Is this possible?